# fetching value from database and setting it in android spinner

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-spinner

hi how is fetching data from database and setting it in spinner on android app.how can i develop dis.the below code is update data from spinner to android mysql database.but i wish to need fetch the data from database and that fetched value is display on my spinner value on android app.how can i develop this..

this is my android code:

```
public class InsertionExample extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8089/XcartLogin/services/update?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/insertData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
Button btninsert;
String selectedItem;

static final String KEY_NAME = "orderid";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_status);
  /*  Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String orderid = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    lblName.setText(orderid); */


    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert1);
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent in = getIntent();
             String orderid = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
            unameProp.setName("Status");//Define the variable name in the web service method
            unameProp.setValue(selectedItem);//Define value for fname variable
            unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable

            request.addProperty(unameProp);
            PropertyInfo idProp =new PropertyInfo();
            idProp.setName("Orderid");//Define the variable name in the web service method
            idProp.setValue(orderid);//Define value for fname variable
            idProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
            request.addProperty(idProp);



              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

              try{
               androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                 TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                  result.setText(response.toString());
             }
           catch(Exception e){

           }
              }
    });

    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    //Dynamically generate a spinner data 
    createSpinnerDropDown();

}

//Add animals into spinner dynamically
private void createSpinnerDropDown() {

    //get reference to the spinner from the XML layout
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    //Array list of animals to display in the spinner
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Q");
    list.add("P");
    list.add("F");
    list.add("I");
    list.add("C");

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    //set the view for the Drop down list
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

}






public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

         selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

       }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

please help me..how can i develop this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ArrayAdapter<?> on your spinner? I used this once.

```
    private class ColorSpinner extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

    public ColorSpinner(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return this.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Here can I set a custom layout or view of each item in the spinner.
        TextView textView = new TextView(PincodeTextView.this.context);
        String message = Integer.toHexString(this.getItem(position)).toUpperCase();
        textView.setBackgroundColor(this.getItem(position));
        textView.setText("0x" + message);
        return textView;
    }
}
```

Then I used this to load the spinner with my `ColorSpinner`:

```
final View colorbox = this.findViewById(R.id.edit_cell_dialog_color);
        if (colorbox instanceof Spinner) {
            ColorSpinner list = new ColorSpinner(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

            // Load from my database the need items in my case a list of color codes.
            int[] colors = PincodeTextView.this.pincodeDB.getColors();

            int indexOfColor = 0;
            // Add each item into the Spinner.
            for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
                list.add(colors[i]);
            }

            ((Spinner) colorbox).setAdapter(list);

        }
```